# Meteor in Minecraft - no mods

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

A pretty long time ago I and my friend were building a giant basketball court, and out of nowhere a big explosion happened and there was then a big crater in the ground. We had absolutely no mods at all and no one could have done it, because we were not playing online (we were playing split-screen on the Bedrock PS3 edition).

I don't know if this was a glitch in the mapmaking, because it was a flat world. I am just wondering.

Comment: It was also not a creeper because it was in peaceful and the crater was on fire and far too big.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no meteors in Minecraft. The closest thing would be a lightning strike during a thunderstorm, but it would only set things on fire, it wouldn't create a crater.

An explosion can be caused by a few things:

- A creeper.
- A wither, or the wither's projectiles.
- TNT.
- An end crystal.
- A bed in the Nether.
- A respawn anchor in the Overworld.

If you were playing in peaceful mode, we can ignore the mobs, which only leaves the explosive items. None of those would explode on their own though. Maybe your friend was pranking you?

If it was a glitch in the world creation (very doubtful in a flat map), it would have been there forever, not appeared suddenly with an explosion.

---

**Edit**: seeing that your custom flat world was made of wood planks, yes, a lightning strike could have caused it, if your world has the "fire spreads" option enabled, which I believe is on by default. However, it could only have hapened during a thunderstorm. Was it raining? Did you see lightning? Usually you get multiple strikes during a storm too, which would mean more than one explosion and crater.

It's also worth noticing @SF's comment: TNT, end crystals and explosive mobs don't cause fires, so the only real option is either the lightning, or a charged respawn anchor.

Comment: I will point out that if they had ignited a large amount of TNT in a loaded chunk, then navigated to an unloaded one via teleport or just really, really fast, it's plausible but improbable that one could've been blown into the new chunk and exploded when the chunk loaded, which would also explain the situation. However, this is, again, highly improbable.

Comment: Okay thanks! Maybe they were, pranking me haha. It was just a wonder I've had for a while. Thanks.

Comment: Btw it was a custom flat world made of wood planks. So maybe it was lightning and the fire burned the wood?

Comment: @AaronHenderson if you feel satisfied enough with this answer, you can accept it with the checkmark below the voting arrows on the upper left corner of the answer. :)

Comment: Oh, I will do that! Thanks, I'm kinda new.

Comment: Creepers, TNT explosions, wither and end crystal don't cause fire. Beds explode only in Nether, which has a roof, it would't arouse expectation of meteorites. Ghast fireball causes explosion and fire but the crater is tiny. Charged respawn anchor leaves a big crater with a lot of fire, and all you need is right-click it to set it off.

Comment: Fire charge or ghast projectile could also be a possibility maybe a ghast went through a nether portal however the chances of this are extremely low, if you're in creative the ghasts won't even target you.